# ag-grid server side sorting/pagination community version Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I installed ag-grid library for datagrid, the Server side sorting and pagination is implemented in NodeJs, for now I'm trying to find which event controllers should be triggered in order to call the related method. Please let know if you have implemented it before.

```html
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-fresh"
    [rowData]="rows"
    [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
    [sideBar]="true"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true"
    [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
    [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"
    (gridReady)="onLoadTableData($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)" event controller to  and by adding

```
const sortState = this.gridApi.getSortModel(); to printSortStateToConsole()
```

```js
 public printSortStateToConsole(params) {
    const sortState = this.gridApi.getSortModel();
    if (sortState.length == 0) {
      console.log("No sort active");
    } else {
      console.log("State of sorting is:", sortState[0].colId, sortState[0].sort);
      this.page.orderDir = sortState[0].sort;
      this.page.orderBy = sortState[0].colId;
      this.reloadTable();

    }
  }
```

```html
  <ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%;"
    id="myGrid"
    class="ag-theme-fresh"
    [rowData]="rows"
    [overlayLoadingTemplate]="overlayLoadingTemplate"
    [sideBar]="true"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [enableServerSideSorting]="true"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true"
    [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"

    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"

    [pagination]="true"
    [paginationPageSize]="page.size"
    (paginationChanged)="printPaginationStateToConsole($event)"

    (sortChanged)="printSortStateToConsole($event)"

    [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"

    (gridReady)="onLoadTableData($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```